# closing a question which already contains the answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Occasionally, a question pops up [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159553/hailstone-recursive-function-python).  Basically, the user posts a question about code that works.  It seems that this question should be closed, but it's difficult to pick a reasoning to close it.  Perhaps adding a statement like "this question answers itself" in the "not a question" category would be helpful?  (Or am I out in right field on this one, and the question really shouldn't be closed after all?)

Comment: "Too localized" is the reason I usually select in a case like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work for you (and everybody else :p) but is obviously not working for the OP (or not working as expected, etc), or they wouldn't be asking a question.

You are not helping the OP by voting to close.  A comment that it works for you and a request for some clarification on the issue the OP is seeing seems to be the way to go to me.  If you don't get any reply, THEN vote to close.  But voting to close without attempting to help the OP at all seems a bit draconian (and rude).

I've seen many people post working code and their question boils down to "why does this work?".  I think these kind of questions are the best.  The poster is obviously trying to learn and should be encouraged to do so.

It's a lot like that "give a man a fish and you've fed him for a day, teach him to fish and you've fed him for a lifetime".  You throw some code at them and they can deal with that particular situation, you teach them why and how and they can then apply it to other, different situations.

Comment: But if others have already made that comment, there's not much more to say ... I'm not advocating closing a post without (someone) providing a good reason.  In fact, I'm advocating the opposite... I don't like that the closed message and the comments might say 2 different things.  Also, how long do you wait before you make the close vote?  10 minutes?  30 minutes? Longer?

Comment: Well, I used to think like that too (see the [question I posted yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145065/167534)). However, sometimes waiting is not the best option (not sure about this particular case).

Comment: I *was* going to say 24 hours as I happen to not have the luxury of being a programmer by profession (or have a computer available to me all day), so I've been known to post a question and leave for work, not to return for 8+ hours.  But a better thought occurred to me...  If there's a request for clarification, check the request date/time against the users "last seen" time.  If the user hasn't been back since the question was asked, leave it be.  If they've been back and not provided the requested clarification, vote to close.  Of course if they haven't been back for a week...  :p