# Close questions without expertise in its main tag?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

a current example:

[JTree: how to make a node auto-expand when it is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471513/jtree-how-to-make-a-node-auto-expand-when-it-is-selected)

while not overly clear to a non-swinger, it's a typical problem - and as such correctly answered and the answer accepted. Nevertheless it got the required 5 votes to be closed - all (except one) from absolute noobs in Swing land (measured by zero to one answer to the tag in all of each voter's answers/questions).

What to do with such overzealous voting?

Comment: The question body is pretty terrible; IMO it should be edited to actually explain the question (not just the title) and reopening would probably be easy

Comment: It's a poor question, no matter what your level of expertise is.

Comment: Btw, you might want to refrain from calling out the close voters as you did. That's never going to be constructive.

Comment: I agree it's a poor question (should have done better when editing ;-) - nevertheless it describes a common problem good enough to be recognizable. The terrible question combined with the correct answer is good enough to be useful for future readers.

Comment: I'm with everyone else here. I'd have taken one look and downvoted; maybe voted to close. As yo're obviously the person who knows most about this subject (who has also interacted with the question) why didn't you edit the question yourself to make it comprehensible/better?

Comment: @BenBrocka, especially as it's now been bought up on meta :-)

Comment: What would you do about tags that don't have a lot of 3K users?

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of experienced Swing users that do not answer questions in that tag. I currently maintain two large Swing applications, but have no time/desire to watch Yet Another Tag.

Comment: The question sounds oddly like a *work request*.

Comment: Just curious... This to the folks who voted down this question... If you have little experience with the tags on a poorly worded question, would the existence of an answer or two dissuade you from voting to close that question?  I guess I'm asking if a question really is poorly worded if it managed to get a reasonable answer from the community.

Comment: @ChrisGerken [No.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144670/should-i-avoid-answering-a-poorly-asked-question-even-if-i-understand-the-op/144673#144673)  In fact, the majority of questions that should be closed can also be answered.  They are closed because they will tend to attract poor quality answers.  (The answer to this question is not a high quality answer; it's not even a complete sentence.)

Comment: @Servy completely disagree - it's _the_ answer to the question, however short it may be.

Comment: @kleopatra I didn't say it wasn't an answer.  I'm saying that it's a poor quality answer and the reason that it's a poor quality answer is that it is a poor quality question (that should just be closed or fixed).  The fact that it answers the question as asked doesn't make it a high quality answer.

Comment: @Servy it's the answer to what the question meant to ask - can't think of much to improve the answer: simple api/behaviour question with a simple api answer. Nothing bad quality I can detect there.

Comment: @kleopatra Exactly.  There is nothing more that the answer can include.  That's because it's a poor quality question.  If the question was of better quality the answer could be better.

Comment: @Servy the site is _full_ of mere api questions/answers .. you want to close/downvote them all?

Comment: @kleopatra Sure.

Comment: @Servy If you really feel that way you should also stop answering them. For example the last answer [you gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12482151/119477) could be answered by simply looking at the language spec (section §7.8.4 if you're interested)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter And yet my answer wasn't just a single sentence fragment with a link to the docs.  It was several paragraphs of an entirely self-sufficient answer to a question that can be rather tricky for those not familiar with that aspect of the language.  It doesn't involve just googling a method/class name, and is an interesting enough issue to warrant me explaining it in my own words.  The fact that the language specs help answer a question, or that enough information is there to do it, is different than saying that linking to the language specs is sufficient to answer a question.

Comment: @Servy you missed my point. If you feel a given type of question should be downvoted and closed you shouldn't also answer it. The fact that you found it interesting or tricky shouldn't enter into it.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter If I feel an answer can be fully solved by just a single link to the documentation I won't answer it.  My point was that the question was sufficiently tricky that it *couldn't* be answered with just such a link.  While all of the information might technically be available in the specs it's often not easily understood, written clearly, in several separate locations, or addressing too general of a case to make a good answer.  In such cases while the specs may have enough information to solve the question, the specs themselves don't qualify as a good answer.

Comment: pip... pip...piiip

Answer (score 20):

As commented by others, it doesn't require expertise in a field to recognize a poorly-written question. However, sometimes there is a legitimately good question hidden behind bad wording.

If you see a question like this, go ahead and edit it to make it clearer. Closing a question is not an irreversible action. If you can't get people to reopen the edited version of the question, flag us and explain how it's been improved and why you believe the question should be reopened. It looks like this one is well on its way to being reopened now that it has been edited for clarity and attention has been brought to it.

One thing you should not do is take it out on the close voters like you did in the comments here. I removed all of your comments, because they were rude and insulting. This is completely unacceptable behavior, and we will not tolerate this here.

Comment: you mean as "WE" our royal high ... moderators :-) BTW, they were not rude, but factual, IMO. Concededly with a slight tendency of annoyance. Actually, never had any luck in contacting the mods in similar disagreements in the past, didn't try the flagging approach, though.

Comment: @kleopatra So then how *did* you try to contact the mods?

Comment: @Servy via the @ heregoesmoderator - obviously the wrong approach in hindsight ;-)